# Django custom QuerySet with custom filter

Tags: django, regex, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

The elements that are stored in Django model is as following

```
class Transcript(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=10000, default="")
    confidence = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

And example data is as following :

```
text = "Word1(1.00-1.50) Word2(1.50-2.15) Word3(2.40-2.80) Word4(3.10-3.25) Word5(3.44-4.12) Word6(4.55-5.12) Word7(6.00-7.00) Word8(7.34-8.00)"
Transcript.object.create(text=text, confidence=99)
```

.

```
Transcript.objects.filter(text = "Word2 Word3")
```

Result : Object found -> Word2(1.50-2.15) Word3(2.40-2.80)

```
Transcript.objects.filter(text = "Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8")
```

Result : Object found -> Word5(3.44-4.12) Word6(4.55-5.12) Word7(6.00-7.00) Word8(7.34-8.00)

```
Transcript.objects.filter(text = "Word3 Word5")
```

Result : Object found - >Word3(2.40-2.80) Word4(3.10-3.25) Word5(3.44-4.12)

```
Transcript.objects.filter(text = "Word10 Word9")
```

Result : Object not found

How can I make these queries using filters and possibly using regex ?

Comment: How are `Word` and `Transcript` related, is there a foreign key from one to the other?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question; Word1(xx.xx-xx.xx) Word2 .. are strings within the text element of the Transcript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
# case sensitive:
Transcript.objects.filter(text__contains = "Word1")

# case insensitive 
Transcript.objects.filter(text__icontains = "Word1")
```

You can combine arguments to look for a transcript with `"Word1"` *and* `"Word2"` like:

```py
Transcript.objects.filter(
    text__contains = "Word1",
    text__contains = "Word2"
)
```

Details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/search/

Comment: What about if I want avoid searching information inside paranthesis, for instance : Not search for (1.00-1.50) but search for Word1 only?

Comment: The example I gave will find all Transcripts with the str `Word1` in the text field, regardless of what comes before or after.

Comment: That is correct, but what if someone searches for "(1.00-1.50)", it is in the text as well. I just want to exclude searching that.